# Entity Framework query performs two queries instead of one

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have encountered a strange behavior in Entity Framework 4.3.1. In the sample below, I am creating a simple model and performing two different queries that I believe should be equivalent. The first one uses the `All` operator while the other one uses a combination of `Where` and `Any` to achieve the same result.

### The first query looks like this:

```
var result = db.Projects
    .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
    .All(p => db.Operations.Any(o => o.Name == "foo" && o.Project.Id == p.Id));
```

When executed, it causes the following **two** database queries, where the "extra" one looks like this:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Project_Id] AS [Project_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Operations] AS [Extent1]
```

### The second query looks like this:

```
var result = !db.Projects // Single query
    .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
    .Where(p => !db.Operations.Any(
                    o => o.Name == "foo" && o.Project.Id == p.Id))
    .Any();
```

This executes a single query, but is messier.

I don't known why the first version causes two queries. This has been causing errors in my code that I have been unable to reproduce in a small example.

**My question is:** Why is the first query performing two database queries? Is this a bug that I should report?

---

Full code below:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLServer; Initial catalog = EFTest;"
                  + " Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

            using (var db = new MyDbContext(connStr)) {
                var result = db.Projects  // Two queries!
                    .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
                    .All(p => db.Operations.Any(
                             o => o.Name == "foo" && o.Project.Id == p.Id));
            }

            using (var db = new MyDbContext(connStr)) {
                var result = !db.Projects // Single query
                    .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
                    .Where(p => !db.Operations.Any(
                             o => o.Name == "foo" && o.Project.Id == p.Id))
                    .Any();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Project {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Operation {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual IDbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public virtual IDbSet<Operation> Operations { get; set; }

        public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a bug.  I just think it's an idiosyncrasy of the way EF generates that particular query.

Is your Project -> Operation relationship mapped?  What about a query something like this?

```
var result = !db.Projects
    .Any(p => p.Id == 1 && !p.Operations.Any(o => o.Name == "foo");
```

Comment: If I add an Operations collection and execute that query, I get a single database query again. I am interested in understanding the reason why EF is performing two queries in the other case because I have been assuming that a single linq query would always produce a single db query.